# Having issues with making a reaction post another embed on Discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, embed

I am having an issue with making an embed have reactions and when you react to it, it will post another embed in the discord chat, this is all trying to make a bot that explains about maths and algebra, I also need to do this in one file, I can't find any tutorials and I canp't figure out how to do it...

Thank you!

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'algebra',
    description: 'This is a test embed command',
    async execute(message, args, Discord, client){
        const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#3B0099')
        .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/a/Wnjoo1L') 
        .setTimestamp() 
        .setAuthor('This was written by (REDACTED)') 
        .setDescription('Once finished reading this you should know a lot about algebra!') 
        .setFooter('Algebra') 
        .addFields(
            {name: 'The Basics Behind Algebra', value: 'Algebra can be a simpal concept if approached correctly, as in you must know what the steps you will take are and complete them in the correct order and way. Algebra mainly focuses on substituting numbers with letters. If you want to learn more about this please react with the letter A'}, 
            {name: 'The Theory of Algebra', value: 'The theory of Algebra is one that is... If you want to learn more about this please react with the letter B'} 
            )
            message.channel.send(newEmbed).then((msg) =>{
                msg.react('1️⃣');
                msg.react('2️⃣');
                msg.react('3️⃣');
                msg.react('4️⃣');
                msg.react('5️⃣');
                msg.react('6️⃣');
                msg.react('7️⃣');
                msg.react('8️⃣');
                msg.react('9️⃣');
                msg.react('');
            }).catch((err)=>{
                throw err;
            });

    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, read the documentation about collectors (https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html)
This is an example

```
    let ageEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('Please, specify your age with the reactions below...')
    .addField('1️⃣', '17-')
    .addField('2️⃣', '18+')
    .setColor('#FF1493')
  let msg = await message.channel.send(ageEmbed)
  await msg.react('1️⃣');
  await msg.react('2️⃣');


  const filter_age = (reaction, user) => {
    return reaction.emoji.name === '1️⃣' || '2️⃣' && user.id === message.author.id && !user.bot;
  }

  const collector_age = msg.createReactionCollector(filter_age, {
    time: 30000,
    max: 1
  });


  collector_age.on('collect', async (reaction, user) => {
    if (reaction.emoji.name === '1️⃣') {
      let embed2 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setDescription(`You reacted with :one:`)
      .addField('Hey', ":one:");
      message.channel.send(embed2)
    } else {
  let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setDescription("You reacted with :two:")
  message.channel.send(embed)
}
```

})

If you react with one, the bot will send an embed saying "You reacted with :one:". Else, the bot will send an embed saying "You reacted with :two: